# Why cant we typecast Float(wrapper) to int(primitive) in java?

Tags: java, floating-point, type-conversion

While I'm doing typecast from `float` to `int` type and typecast from `Integer` to `int` it is working. But while i am trying to typecast from `Float` to `int` type I'm getting the error as "incompatible type". Why can't we typecast from wrapper to primitive type (Except for its own primitive type).

Comment: Why the c++ tag. It is very different to java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast Double to Integer in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102318/cast-double-to-integer-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Becuase, `Float` is a class type. It derives from `Object`. But `int` is a primitive type. You can use `floatValue()` for conversion.

Comment: Yes, thats fine.. Please chech the below code.... Integer i = 10;  Float f = (float)i; --->(1)   and Float f1 = (Float)i; ---->(2).... Here statement (1) is working but not (2)... why...?

Answer (score 1):

Well that's kind of what makes the difference between wrapper classes and primitives. It wrapps the value around a Class with useful methods.
That's why for converting to int, you'd have to either use

```
Float f;
int i = (int)(f.floatValue());
```

or of course

```
Float f;
int i = f.intValue();
```

In the sense that a wrapper is a class that wrapps around a certain value, it's more logical to extract a value from that class rather than converting a class to a value.

Note the source code for java.lang.Float:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Float.java#Float.intValue%28%29
Maybe that makes things clearer.