# Convert/Cast Double to int? (Object to primitive type)

Tags: java

How do I convert/cast a `Double` object to an `int`?

```
Double d = new Double(12.34);
int i = 12 //is what I'm looking for
```

If I had a `double` I would just use:

```
double z = 12.34;
int i = (int)z;
```

Note: I want it to truncate the `Double` (so 12.9 becomes 12) because I know that `d` actually was an integer that was converted to a Double.
I.e. I want to call (int) on a `Double`.

Comment: I could not find a question that asked what I was looking for (i.e. Object to primitive) and want to provide the answer here so that it comes up in searches. The closest I found was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102318/cast-double-to-integer-in-java

Comment: If you are unhappy with truncation (due to possible precision loss errors), then why don't you try `round()`?

Comment: @AntonSamsonov I want the truncation. I am looking to call the (int) cast, but on a Double not a double.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To perform this operation you need to call the `intValue` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#intValue%28%29) on the `Double` object:

```
int i = d.intValue();
```

This method performs a cast, into an `int` value, on the `double` value wrapped within the `Double` object, `d`.

Note that it does not check for `null` before attempting this.

Comment: _This method performs a cast on the double value in Double_ if `d` is a `double`, then this will not be wrapped, this will not compile. Here this works because `d` is a `Double`. The explanation are wrong. A primitive value doesn't provide methods

Comment: Correct, the question is how to perform a cast to int on a `Double` object. I've edited the explanation, does this make it clearer?

Comment: _This method performs a cast into an `int` value on the `double` value wrapped within the Double object, d._ would seems more logic. Because I keep reading that you are casting the `Double` in a `double` because this is not really clear

Comment: @AxelH I agree, I've edited the answer as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a cast you can use

```
Double d = 12.34;
int i = (int) (double) d;
```

You can't cast from `Double` to `int` in one step.