# Remove digits which are in the decimal place

Tags: android, decimal

I get a double value (eg. -3.1234) which contains a value in decimals (0.1234 in this case). I want to remove the value in decimal value (in this case I wanted the value -3). How do I do it? I know how to remove the decimal if the decimal only has 0, but in this case I don't have the decimal value as 0.

Anyways here is the code for that:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
format.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);

Double asdf = 2.0;
Double asdf2 = 2.11;
Double asdf3 = 2000.11;
System.out.println( format.format(asdf) );
System.out.println( format.format(asdf2) );
System.out.println( format.format(asdf3) );
/*
prints-:
2
2.11
2000.11
*/
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26589526/7505436

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to print it :

```
String val = String.format("%.0f", 2.11)
// val == "2"
```

If you want to keep the double type but without decimals :

```
double val = Math.floor(2.11);
// val == 2.000
```

If you don't care about type you can cast the double into int :

```
int val = (int) 2.11;
// val == 2

//double as object
int val = myDouble.integerValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `intValue()` method of `Double` to get the integer part.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast it to `int`

```
int i=(int)2.12
System.out.println(i); // Prints 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Round up decimal value & convert it into integer;

```
Integer intValue = Integer.valueOf((int) Math.round(doubleValue)));
```

Comment: Wow, maybe you should add an "(int)" in front of Integer.valueOf, just to be sure... :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.studytonight.com/java/type-casting-in-java check out type conversion in java

```
    double asdf2 = 2.11;
    int i = (int)asdf2;
    System.out.println(asdf2);
    System.out.println(i);

    Output:

    2.11`
    2
```