# Get int from Vector of Objects

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I use a method to get Data from a database and store it in a vector. The method will always return a Vector of Objects where the Object datatype can be either a Date, a Double or a String. In my case, I know that I'm getting a Double, but I want to convert it to an int. is there any easier way than:

```
System.out.println((int)Double.parseDouble(vector1.get(1).toString()));
```

Other methods I tried that didn't work:

```
System.out.println((Integer)vector1.get(1)); // java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double incompatible with java.lang.Integer

System.out.println((int)vector1.get(1));
```

Thanks in advance for any constructive response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102318/cast-double-to-integer-in-java), we can transform the code into

```
Double d = vector1.get(1);
Integer i = d.intValue();
```

And I would assume here that if you have some array, maybe you want to transform all of the data there from `Double` into `Integer`

```
vector1.stream().mapToInt(n -> n.intValue()).mapToObj(Integer::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
vector1.stream().mapToInt(Double::intValue).mapToObj(Integer::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use intValue() to get int value.

```
Double b = new Double((double)vector1.get(1));   
int value = b.intValue();
```

Comment: "Cannot cast from Object to double" - error https://i.imgur.com/tLMLPOg.png

Comment: I have already tested this. It is working for me. Vector<Object> objVector = new Vector<Object>(10);
        objVector.add(new Double(1.5));        
        Double b1 = new Double((double)objVector.get(0));   
        int value = b1.intValue(); 
        System.out.println(value);

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.round(double) to get the int value. As

Double d = Double.parseDouble(vector1.get(1));

int v = (int) Math.round(d);